# Lack of umlaut in Standard Dutch Plurals

Tags: germanic-languages, dutch

I've never paid much attention to Dutch, but I've noticed in comparisons such as charts that Dutch does not have plurals formed with an umlaut.
Hence:
Feet—Füße—voeten
I thought it was odd, and when I checked my copy of Old English and its Closest Relatives, Old Low Franconian(although not the direct ancestor of Standard Dutch) does have at least one instance of umlaut in plurals:
Bock–buckin dat.pl.
My question is simply why. I'm asking in Linguistics because it's about the historical basis.

Comment: Are you sure "buckin" shows umlaut rather than some other kind of vowel change? I'm not familiar with Old Low Franconian orthography: does the "u" here necessarily represent some front vowel like /ʏ/?

Comment: You might find the following Wikipedia article helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_umlaut#I-mutation_in_Dutch I'm not sure if it really explains "why," but it gives some more examples and mentions some regional variation.

Comment: Due to spelling inconsistencies, "u" probably does at least occasionally represent /ʏ/. At least according to this book. Of course, o->ʏ is not a regular umlaut change, so perhaps it is a different thing. But it's still a change of vowel.

Comment: That wikipedia article was pretty helpful.